# Label Printing in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I was doing a label printing report in ssrs. Where I need to skip a number of rows and columns so that i can reuse the sheets. i.e start printing in row 3 column 10?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See my response to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041738/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-blank-row-to-an-ssrs-dataset-based-on-parameter/46577941#46577941

Answer (score 0):

You can do this within the SQL query.  Calculate the starting position for the printer based on the columnStart and RowStart, then return that number of blank rows in your result.

ie for a 3 column 8 row report:
if StartingColumnn was 2 and Starting position was 3rd row, I'd return 10 blank rows at the start of the recordset - it would then start printing from the 11th position